# JRUBY - RAILS 3 - TOMCAT 7 Deploy failed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, jruby, tomcat7

I have my rails 3 app. This work fine in netbeans with webrick.

I create this application with:

Jruby jruby 1.6.5.1 (ruby-1.8.7-p330)
Rails 3.1.3

My bundle work fine.

Mi gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.3'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'
gem 'jruby-openssl'
gem 'json'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass',   '~> 3.1.12'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  end
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

For create .war file from application, I have installed with bundle all gem required.
I have installed wrable and run

> wrable config

and then

> wrable

This create the .war file.

I put this file on the webapps tomcat7 directory and start the server.

Server starting fine, catalina.out logs no errors but...

When I try to go at the address when tomcat manager says is my application, I have more time to attendo for view just a withe page. the application name is "cameraAccreditiGiornalisti". So, the address is localhost:8080/cameraAccreditiGiornalisti => white page!

I read all guides in the web but I not say where is the problem!! Not have a log to look and the white page... no error!

Please help!

Comment: Tomcat log files should have more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I found out that `war` file does not include `web.xml` file, which is necessary for Tomcat to start up the webapp. I did not found any info why warble does not generate that file, as it should.

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved... I read a wrong log file.... Maybe for your problem check the file warble.rb in projectdirectory/config. This is my and work:

```
    # Disable Rake-environment-task framework detection by uncommenting/setting to false
# Warbler.framework_detection = false

# Warbler web application assembly configuration file
Warbler::Config.new do |config|
  # Features: additional options controlling how the jar is built.
  # Currently the following features are supported:
  # - gemjar: package the gem repository in a jar file in WEB-INF/lib
  # - executable: embed a web server and make the war executable
  # - compiled: compile .rb files to .class files
  # config.features = %w(gemjar)

  # Application directories to be included in the webapp.
  config.dirs = %w(app config lib log vendor tmp)


  # Additional files/directories to include, above those in config.dirs
  # config.includes = FileList["db"]

  # Additional files/directories to exclude
  # config.excludes = FileList["lib/tasks/*"]

  # Additional Java .jar files to include.  Note that if .jar files are placed
  # in lib (and not otherwise excluded) then they need not be mentioned here.
  # JRuby and JRuby-Rack are pre-loaded in this list.  Be sure to include your
  # own versions if you directly set the value
  # config.java_libs += FileList["lib/java/*.jar"]

  # Loose Java classes and miscellaneous files to be included.
  # config.java_classes = FileList["target/classes/**.*"]
  #config.java_classes = FileList["log4j.properties"]

  # One or more pathmaps defining how the java classes should be copied into
  # the archive. The example pathmap below accompanies the java_classes
  # configuration above. See http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/String.html#M000017
  # for details of how to specify a pathmap.
  # config.pathmaps.java_classes << "%{target/classes/,}p"

  # Bundler support is built-in. If Warbler finds a Gemfile in the
  # project directory, it will be used to collect the gems to bundle
  # in your application. If you wish to explicitly disable this
  # functionality, uncomment here.
  # config.bundler = false

  # An array of Bundler groups to avoid including in the war file.
  # Defaults to ["development", "test"].
  # config.bundle_without = []

  # Other gems to be included. If you don't use Bundler or a gemspec
  # file, you need to tell Warbler which gems your application needs
  # so that they can be packaged in the archive.
  # For Rails applications, the Rails gems are included by default
  # unless the vendor/rails directory is present.
  # config.gems += ["activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", "jruby-openssl"]
  # config.gems << "tzinfo"
  config.gems += ["activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", "jruby-openssl"]



  # Uncomment this if you don't want to package rails gem.
  # config.gems -= ["rails"]

  # The most recent versions of gems are used.
  # You can specify versions of gems by using a hash assignment:
  # 
  config.gems["rails"] = "3.2.1"
  # You can also use regexps or Gem::Dependency objects for flexibility or
  # finer-grained control.
  # config.gems << /^merb-/
  # config.gems << Gem::Dependency.new("merb-core", "= 0.9.3")

  # Include gem dependencies not mentioned specifically. Default is
  # true, uncomment to turn off.
  # config.gem_dependencies = false

  # Array of regular expressions matching relative paths in gems to be
  # excluded from the war. Defaults to empty, but you can set it like
  # below, which excludes test files.
  # config.gem_excludes = [/^(test|spec)\//]

  # Pathmaps for controlling how application files are copied into the archive
  # config.pathmaps.application = ["WEB-INF/%p"]

  # Name of the archive (without the extension). Defaults to the basename
  # of the project directory.
  # config.jar_name = "mywar"

  # Name of the MANIFEST.MF template for the war file. Defaults to a simple
  # MANIFEST.MF that contains the version of Warbler used to create the war file.
  # config.manifest_file = "config/MANIFEST.MF"

  # When using the 'compiled' feature and specified, only these Ruby
  # files will be compiled. Default is to compile all \.rb files in
  # the application.
  # config.compiled_ruby_files = FileList['app/**/*.rb']

  # === War files only below here ===

  # Path to the pre-bundled gem directory inside the war file. Default
  # is 'WEB-INF/gems'. Specify path if gems are already bundled
  # before running Warbler. This also sets 'gem.path' inside web.xml.
  # config.gem_path = "WEB-INF/vendor/bundler_gems"

  # Files for WEB-INF directory (next to web.xml). This contains
  # web.xml by default. If there is an .erb-File it will be processed
  # with webxml-config. You may want to exclude this file via
  # config.excludes.
  # config.webinf_files += FileList["jboss-web.xml"]

  # Files to be included in the root of the webapp.  Note that files in public
  # will have the leading 'public/' part of the path stripped during staging.
  # config.public_html = FileList["public/**/*", "doc/**/*"]

  # Pathmaps for controlling how public HTML files are copied into the .war
  # config.pathmaps.public_html = ["%{public/,}p"]

  # Value of RAILS_ENV for the webapp -- default as shown below
  config.webxml.rails.env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'production'

  # Application booter to use, one of :rack, :rails, or :merb (autodetected by default)
  # config.webxml.booter = :rails

  # Set JRuby to run in 1.9 mode.
  # config.webxml.jruby.compat.version = "1.9"

  # When using the :rack booter, "Rackup" script to use.
  # - For 'rackup.path', the value points to the location of the rackup
  # script in the web archive file. You need to make sure this file
  # gets included in the war, possibly by adding it to config.includes
  # or config.webinf_files above.
  # - For 'rackup', the rackup script you provide as an inline string
  #   is simply embedded in web.xml.
  # The script is evaluated in a Rack::Builder to load the application.
  # Examples:
  # config.webxml.rackup.path = 'WEB-INF/hello.ru'
  # config.webxml.rackup = %{require './lib/demo'; run Rack::Adapter::Camping.new(Demo)}
  # config.webxml.rackup = require 'cgi' && CGI::escapeHTML(File.read("config.ru"))

  # Control the pool of Rails runtimes. Leaving unspecified means
  # the pool will grow as needed to service requests. It is recommended
  # that you fix these values when running a production server!
  # config.webxml.jruby.min.runtimes = 2
  # config.webxml.jruby.max.runtimes = 4
  config.webxml.jruby.min.runtimes = 2
  config.webxml.jruby.max.runtimes = 4

  # JNDI data source name
  # config.webxml.jndi = 'jdbc/rails'
end
```